# Simple image rotation with pure javascript, no jQuery

Tags: javascript

trying to come up with very simple image rotation using pure javascript without jQuery.

Something that I could call like that and it could place the image in same spot rotating it one by one.

```
rotator('<a href="link1"><img src="image1.gif"/ ></a>','<a href="link1"><img src="image1.gif"/ ></a>');
```

maybe someone could suggest a way of doing it? thank you.

UPDATE: By Rotation I meant, one disappears, another appears. Not angle rotation.

Comment: What flexibility is required? By that I mean would 0, 90, 180, 270 degrees suffice? Would the action be dynamic or procedural?

Comment: i meant one appears and another disappears. no angle rotation.

Comment: I'm just curious, why no jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of steps beyond the call of duty and probably isn't the best solution but nonetheless. A full Javascript function (handles by tag not by image)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

        /*rotate
                    desc: Rotate a set of first level child objects based on tag name
                    params:
                            id = Rotate elements container id
                            tag = Tag (nodeName - see textNode issue) of DOM objects to be cycled
            */
            function rotate(id, tag)
            {

                    /*Normalise string for later comparison*/
                    tag = tag.toLowerCase();

                    /*Get container DOM Object*/
                    var el = document.getElementById(id),
                            visibleIdentified = false;
                            hasBeenSet = false,
                            firstMatchingChild = false;;

                    /*Iterate over children*/
                    for(i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++){

                            /*Set child to var for ease of access*/
                            var child = el.childNodes[i];

                            /*If element has the correct nodeName and is a top level chlid*/
                            if(child.parentNode == el && child.nodeName.toLowerCase() == tag){

                                    /*Set first matching child in case the rotation is already on the last image*/
                                    if(!firstMatchingChild)
                                            firstMatchingChild = child;                

                                    /*If child is visible */
                                    if(child.style.display == "block"){

                                            /*Take note that the visible element has been identified*/
                                            visibleIdentified = true;

                                            /*Toggle its visibility (display attribute)*/
                                            child.style.display = "none";

                                    /*Once the visibile item has been identified*/
                                    }else if(visibleIdentified){

                                            /*If the next item to become visible has been set*/
                                            if(hasBeenSet){

                                                    /*Toggle visibility (display attribute)*/
                                                    child.style.display = "none"
                                            }

                                            /*Catch the next item to become visible*/
                                            else{

                                                    /*Toggle visibility (display attribute)*/
                                                    child.style.display = "block";

                                                    /*Take note that the next item has been made visible*/
                                                    hasBeenSet = true;
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }

                    /*If the hasBeenSet is false then the first item is to be made visible
                      - Only do so if the firstMatchingChild was identified, more or less redundant
                            exception handling*/
                    if(!hasBeenSet && firstMatchingChild)
                                    firstMatchingChild.style.display = "block";

            }

            /*Declare cycle*/
            setInterval("rotate('test','div')",1000);
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <!-- Example container -->
            <div id="test">
                    <div style="display:block">fire</div>
                    <div style="display:none">water</div>
                    <div style="display:none">shoe</div>
                    <div style="display:none">bucket</div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your specific question I haven't seen before, but your basic premise has been asked many times. The reason why you can't find a call like

```
rotate('<img src="1" />', '<img src="2" />');
```

is because it is a bad idea according to programming practices. You are mixing content with script. Client-side web design relies on sandboxing certain features to speed development and make debugging easier. Content, Styling and Scripting are the major areas. Here you mix content (images) with scripting. You should really use one of the many existing image rotation scripts that rely on taking existing markup and rotating them.

```
<img src="a" />
<img src="b" />
<script>rotateImages();</script>
```

If you want to do it your way then you will need to parse your strings and then create element nodes based on them. Honestly I don't think its worth the time to code one up in that format unless this is for curiosity's sake.

Answer (score -1):

I am going to answer my own question as I came up with solution by my own. Sorry if I did not explain well and I hope it could be useful to someone as well. I had to avoid jQuery for a special reason, sometimes its just has to be that way. Here is the code, feel free to comment and improve... a working version is here http://jsbin.com/oxujuf/3

```
function rotator(options) {

        var a = options.delay;
        var b = options.media;
        var mediaArr = [];

        for(var i = 0, j = b.length; i < j; i++) {          
            mediaArr.push(b[i].img);
        }

        document.write('<div id="rotatorContainer"></div>');
        var container = document.getElementById('rotatorContainer');
        var Start = 0;

        rotatorCore();

        function rotatorCore() {
            Start = Start + 1;

            if(Start >= mediaArr.length)
                Start = 0;
            container.innerHTML = mediaArr[Start];          
            setTimeout(rotatorCore, a);

        }

    }
```

And then later you may call it like that, with a simple API.

```
   rotator({

        delay : 3500,
        media : [{
            img : '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-h-c-149-300-7.jpg" width="149" height="300" border="0" />'
        }, {
            img : '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-h-c-149-300-2.jpg" width="149" height="300" />'
        }]

    });
```

Answer (score -2):

This is covered on many older forums and blogs.
Here are a couple links:

http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1012

http://www.reachcustomersonline.com/2008/03/19/09.38.04/?doing_wp_cron=1326819656

Comment: yes, but they do not provide an option to simple call a function and pass array of images as parameter anywhere in html document like I showed as an example.

Comment: Either change your API or modify existing solution to fit your API. I would recommend the former. Are you asking here for someone to do it for you?